# Pseudo Element Before / After

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm using an image to the left of a link.
Right now, I use the ::before attribute for the image to show, however it shows slightly above the link.

I need to have it aligned. Here's a pic:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gipyr.png)

The code I'm using is:

```
 .vocabulary-duration::before {
     content: "";
     float: left;
     font-family: "FontAwesome";
     font-size: 18px;
     padding-right: 0.5em;
 }
```

Comment: Try vertical-align: middle;

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `float` and use `inline` or `inline-block` and then use `vertical-align`

```css
.vocabulary-duration::before {
  content: "";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="vocabulary-duration">asdf</div>
```